# import hibernate-orm as gradle project in STS eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, import, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Trying to import gradle project(hibernate-orm) in eclipse and get exception during build model:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':hibernate-core'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:463)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:75)
at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:439)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:434)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:89)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:48)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DelegatingBuildModelAction.run(DelegatingBuildModelAction.java:42)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:94)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:116)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:61)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.execute(HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.java:21)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StopConnectionAfterExecution.execute(StopConnectionAfterExecution.java:27)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:121)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1$1.run(Daemon.java:123)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
 Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'MatrixTestingPlugin'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:90)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$100(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$2.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:841)
at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at hibernate_core_7q7cqc9dhu87lh08q18h1n9i8.run(/home/user/development/linux/hibernate-workspace/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/hibernate-core.gradle:3)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
... 55 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.build.gradle.util.Jdk.<init>(Jdk.java:64)
at org.hibernate.build.gradle.util.Jdk.<init>(Jdk.java:52)
at org.hibernate.build.gradle.testing.matrix.MatrixTestingPlugin.<init>(MatrixTestingPlugin.groovy:65)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:63)
... 69 more
```

How to fix this exception? I'm using gradle eclipse plugin. The same problem appears then i import project as eclipse project(successfully) and try to add Gradle support after that.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':hibernate-core'.

> Could not create plugin of type 'MatrixTestingPlugin'.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm?

Comment: Cannot find instruction for eclipse import there.

Comment: Click on the first link, labeled "Building Hibernate ORM", and you'll find instructions.

Comment: I need import project in eclipse. Not build it in console.

Comment: For christ sake, read what is written in the page: To create the Eclipse project files you can run `./gradlew eclipse`.
After changes to the dependencies you need to clean the project files and recreate them: `./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`. Once you've done that, you have an Eclipse project ready to import. This is, BTW, the default procedure to follow to create an Eclipse project with Gradle.

Answer (score 7):

JAVA_HOME must be specified in environment. For example in /etc/environment.

Comment: Yep - I got the same problem - just edit the .bash_profile like below -JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home;
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Answer (score 0):

The last comment is correct. The right procedure is:

```
./gradlew eclipse
```

If changes are made to the dependencies it is best to run:

```
./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
```

See also https://community.jboss.org/wiki/BuildingHibernateORM4x5x#Eclipse and https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ContributingToHibernateUsingEclipse

Comment: No. The question was about importing hibernate-orm project as Gradle project in Eclipse, not creating eclipse project from hibernate-orm source.

Comment: There is the Gradle STS Support (http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/latest/reference/html/gradle/). No idea whether is works. IMO the best way for now is the built-in Gradle eclipse plugin.

Comment: What do you mean built-in? I have eclipse-juno-x86_64 and there is no Gradle plugins there. The question above is related exactly to STS Gradle support. Fixing question.

Comment: I meant the plugin which is part of Gradle and executed via 'gradlew eclipse'. I am not so sure why it is so important for you to use anything else. What expectations do you have after the import. The project files generated by the Gradle plugin set up all the modules and classpaths. You should be able to get started right away. I don't know what the STS plugin offers on top of that.

Comment: Looking at your stack trace one more I see that there seems to be a problem with the MatrixTestingPlugin. This plugin is a custom plugin which allows testing against multiple databases. It is part of the buildSrc folder. My guess is that the STS plugin cannot cope with that or maybe there is a way to add these type of custom plugins.

Comment: I've did import as eclipse project after executing ./gradlew eclipse. After that i need to see which files compiles and which are not(highlighted red). After import as eclipse project i cannot see that because project is not built. After that i try to add STS Gradle support to generated eclipse projects(to build them in ide to get not compiling sources marked red in Project explorer). And when i try to add STS Gradle support to project i get same error.

Comment: Why do you not just build from the command line then? The project compiles just fine, however, there are generated classes which the IDE needs to be able to build the project from within the IDE. Build the project once from the command line and then refresh the IDE.

Comment: Because I' like speed in programming, short test-code-test cycles in programming in general, unit testing instead of deploying and stuff. Everybody likes speed. Anyway i've got feedback from https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3019 I think i will answer myself in a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a java envronment make sure that its a full java install, ie a version with javac included.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to /etc/environment and it worked in seconds, WOW. Thanks to @Vyacheslav

> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386"